# benchmarking ftp in 3 methods of virtualization

Tags: lvm, virtualization, kvm, xen, lxc

My Bachelor Final Project is about benchmarking visualization methods with ftp, web and mysql services:

installing Debian on xen (para-visualization) kvm and lxc with equal resources config (equal CPU cores , RAM size and HDD size)

everything is ok but:

[Para-ftp Benchmark Jmeter Screenshot](http://torabkheslat.ir/files/para-ftp.png)

[LXC-ftp Benchmark Jmeter Screenshot](http://torabkheslat.ir/files/lxc-ftp.png)

I used dedicated Hard Disk with LVM partitions for all lxc , xen and kvm.

My question is: why does this result happen while in other tests with services such as MySQL [for DBMS test] and Apache [for web service], the container based systems go about 2X faster than paravirtualized system?

Comment: You do realize that the interpretation of that data would be the scientific contribution of your work and if you don't do it yourself you're technically a fraud and won't get a degree. People who would hand out Bachelor project like that read SE too, you know.

Comment: On topic: In general, paravirtualization should always be faster than full virtualization, especially when the VMs are located on the same host. However, depending on the technology you use for storage, a container based system with NAS, maybe even FC, can outperform paravirtualized systems that share the same harddrive(-controller).

Comment: @user1129682
this my research about performance differences between Visualization methods
in this three methods:

1-Full Visualization (kvm)
2-Para Visualization (xen)
3-OS-level Visualization (lxc)

in comparing kvm and xen with all tests results are good
in comparing xen and lxc in ftp test,containers transferring speed is about half of xen

Comment: compare the lxc containers on the same host vs the containers on different hosts. it may be a scheduling issue